# How to parse a time

Tags: python

Is there a way to parse the following Time without using something hacky like `s.spilt()` a bunch of times?

```
s = 'PT1H28M26S'
```

I would like to get:

```
num_mins = 88
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove P, T and M with translate then slice of the seconds extracting hrs and mins with split:

```
s = 'PT1H28M26S'

hr, min = map(int, s.translate(None,"PTMS")[:-2].split("H"))
print(hr,min)
(1, 28)
```

If you may have single digits for seconds, rstrip them off:

```
hr,min =  map(int,s[2:].rstrip("0123456789S")[:-1].split("H"))
```

Some timings show find is the most efficient and time the least:

```
In [38]: r  = re.compile(r"PT(\d+)H(\d+)M(\d+)S")

In [39]: %%timeit
   ....: match = r.search(s)
   ....: h, m, _ = map(int, match.groups())
   ....: 
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.16 µs per loop

In [40]: timeit t=time.strptime('PT1H28M2S', "PT%HH%MM%SS")
100000 loops, best of 3: 13.3 µs per loop

In [41]: timeit hr, min = map(int,s[2:].rstrip("0123456789S")[:-1].split("H"))
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.96 µs per loop
In [43]: timeit num_mins = int(s[s.find('H')-1]) * 60 +   int(s[s.find('H')+1:s.find('M')]) 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.54 µs per loop
```

Comment: Not sure this `[:-2]` part will work. Note that hours have only one digit in the example, so I would bet that seconds could also have only one digit, e.g. `6` instead of `06`.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html):

```
>>> match = re.search(r"PT(\d+)H(\d+)M(\d+)S", s)
>>> h, m, s = map(int, match.groups())
>>> num_mins = h * 60 + m
>>> num_mins
88
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [*time.strptime*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime) function to convert a string to a date object, then simply you can get the `hour` and `minute` with `tm_hour` and `tm_min` methods :

```
>>> import time
>>> t=time.strptime('PT1H28M26S', "PT%HH%MM%SS")
time.struct_time(tm_year=1900, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=1, tm_min=28, tm_sec=26, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=-1)

>>> t.tm_hour * 60 + t.tm_min
88
```

Comment: If the hours counted exceeds 23, this breaks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use basic slice and string methods:

```
s = 'PT1H28M26S'
num_mins = int(s[s.find('H')-1]) * 60 + int(s[s.find('H')+1:s.find('M')])
```

Comment: actually the most efficient solution +1

Comment: Yep, @PadraicCunningham, I actually wrote 3 tests for the regex, time, and my version. Thanks for the +1.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I'd call the split solution "hacky." It's not the shortest, but it's pretty simple:

```
import re
HMS = [ 60, 1, 0 ]
parts = [int(x) for x in re.split('\D', s) if x != ""]
num_mins = sum([ v * u for v, u in zip(parts, HMS) ])
```