# Parsing time string with optional hour, min and secs to datetime.time

Tags: python, python-datetime

Some examples:

```
'PT1H28M26S'
'PT5H23M26S'
'PT3H8M'
'PT4M'
```

I have found some other questions like this, but the answers on them aren't flexible enough. For example using [regex, map & groups](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29311028/14478886) does not work on the last two examples. This line:

```
 h, m, s = map(int, match.groups())
```

gives the following error when trying the something like the last two examples:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'

Same problem with using something like:

```
t=time.strptime('PT1H28M26S', "PT%HH%MM%SS")
```

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55787166/14478886) or as second answer to the previous question I linked. And since all three of them can either be there or not, putting something like this in an if-statement would require something with a lot of lines as there are 6 combinations possible(3 of them either appearing or not).

Any way to make these into a datetime no matter what they look like?

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29310954/how-to-parse-a-time/29311162

Comment: @Immaturetrader thanks for the response, but that is the first one I linked in my post. Like I said, the answers on this question are not flexible enough

Answer (score 1):

You can make the capture groups optional, and then extract hours, mins and secs from your string if they exist and then convert them into a `datetime.time` object -

```
import datetime
import re

def get_datetime(s):
    matches = re.search(r"PT(\d+H)?(\d+M)?(\d+S)?", s).groups()
    hours, mins, secs = [int(x[:-1]) if x else 0 for x in matches]
    return datetime.time(hours, mins, secs)

times = ['PT1H28M26S','PT5H23M26S','PT3H8M','PT4M']
for t in times:
    print(get_datetime(t))
```

**Output:**

```
01:28:26
05:23:26
03:08:00
00:04:00
```

---

Can be converted to following one-liner(I'd rather avoid it though because of readability)

```
datetime.time(*[int(x[:-1]) if x else 0 for x in re.search(r"PT(\d+H)?(\d+M)?(\d+S)?", s).groups()])
```